# monaco editor resize dynamically in angular

Tags: angular, ngx-monaco-editor

#### My doubt

I've created a *monaco code editor* as a angular custom component. I want to make this component responsive.

I render editor component (consider child) in some test component (consider parent).

If I increase the test component's width and height, that time it calls one function and fires a custom event.

#### Raise custom event

```
var codeEditorResizeEvent = new CustomEvent("codeEditorResize", { 'detail': component });
document.body.dispatchEvent(codeEditorResizeEvent);
```

*Monaco code editor* component catching that event like this:

```
fromEvent(document.body, 'codeEditorResize').subscribe(res => {
     console.log("*************", res) //statement exicuted on firing some button from other component
     //resize monaco editor here
});
```

I want to resize the *monaco code editor* (custom component) as well.

How can I make this resize dynamically??

---

My code editor component:

#### Component class

```
export class CodeEditorComponent implements OnInit {
  editorOptions = { theme: 'vs-dark', language: 'javascript' };
  
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {

   //register custom event browser level and catching the event 
   fromEvent(document.body, 'codeEditorResize').subscribe(res => {
       console.log("*************", res) //statement exicuted on firing some button from other component
       //resize monaco editor here
   });
}


loadTypes(event?: any) {
    const monaco = (<any>window).monaco;
    const typeFiles: string[] = [
      'person.d.ts',
      'app-session.ts',
      'apptor-form.ts'
    ];

    monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
        noLib: true,
        allowNonTsExtensions: true
    });
 
}
```

#### Angular part

```
<ngx-monaco-editor style="height:100%" [options]="editorOptions" #editor [(ngModel)]="code" (onInit)="loadTypes($event)"></ngx-monaco-editor>
```

#### The test component

(which is firing the event from other component)

```
resize(component: any) {
  var codeEditorResizeEvent = new CustomEvent("codeEditorResize", { 'detail': component });
  document.body.dispatchEvent(codeEditorResizeEvent);
}
```

Comment: Any one have any solution???